# phpmyadmin/MySQL Time-Event

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a question relating to phpmyadmin respectively MySQL in common. I wanted to ask if there is a kind of "Time Event", that performs a command/operation if a specific time is reached. For example you can imagine a table with two columns 'status' and 'Date_Expiry'. What I want to do is changing the 'status' value from 0  to 1 when the current date reaches the Date given in the 'Date_Expiry' column. I hope you understand what I mean. I am thankful for all kind of help and information.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL offers an event scheduler (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) and phpMyAdmin offers an interface to manage it (via the Events menu).

So you could schedule an event that runs, say, once per day and does the verifications you want.

Comment: Hey Marc, thanks for your response. I have read about the event scheduler before and for sure it is a possibility to reach the behavior I described, more or less. But for my specific task it is important that the status changes exactly at the given 'Date_Expiry', because I want to use the 'status'-value for determining if a process is expired  or not. So with your suggestion (say the event runs once a day) I could have a difference of nearly 1 day between the 'Date_Expiry' is reached and the status is changed and that is not really suitable for me.

Comment: The other posibility is to choose a very small time increment for the event to run (say 1 minute or so). But wouldn't that slow down my database-performance dramatically?

Comment: Sounds like what you really need, then, is to do your query against the 'Date_Expiry' field instead of 'status' -- you should be able to query about whether 'Date_Expiry' is after NOW() instead of whether 'status' is 1.